# TestNG Installation Warning Message

Tags: testng

when i am trying to install TestNg in My PC i got below warning message and it not be install in my PC.how to elucidation it.

Warning: You are installing software that contains unsigned content. The authenticity or validity of this software cannot be established. Do you want to continue

Comment: Do you trust them?
What Operating System are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be safe, as they said it themselves:

https://books.google.fr/books?id=9CuP8S2glWQC&lpg=PT47&ots=-Bvu-G7o-j&dq=testng%20You%20are%20installing%20software%20that%20contains%20unsigned%20content.%20The%20authenticity%20or%20validity%20of%20this%20software%20cannot%20be%20established.%20Do%20you&hl=fr&pg=PT47#v=onepage&q=testng%20You%20are%20installing%20software%20that%20contains%20unsigned%20content.%20The%20authenticity%20or%20validity%20of%20this%20software%20cannot%20be%20established.%20Do%20you&f=false